# No Subgroup of $S_7$ of order 15

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

If $S_7$ is the symmetric group on 7 elements and $H \leq S_7$ is a subgroup with $|H| = 15$, then $H$ is a subgroup of order $pq$ where $p \nmid q-1$ for $p=3$ and $q=5$.  This would imply that $H$ is cyclic.

I think the remaining portion of this proof relies on arriving at a contradiction when assuming that $S_7$ has a cyclic subgroup of order 15, but I'm struggling with the details.  If $H$ is such a cyclic subgroup, then we can write $H = \langle \pi \rangle$ for some $\pi \in S_7$, but $\pi$ can be written as a product of disjoint cycles.  So $\pi$ might look like

$$
\pi = (1,2)(3,4,5)(6,7), \quad \text{or}\quad \pi = (1,2,3,4)(5,6,7), 
$$

etc.  For either of the two examples above, the order of the cyclic subgroup generated by $\pi$ should be the least common multiple of all of the cycle lengths, i.e., least common multiple of 2 and 3 which is 6, or the least common multiple of 4 and 3 which is 12.

How can I show that the least common multiple of the disjoint cycles for any possible $\pi$ cannot be equal to 15?

Comment: Since the order of a product of disjoint cycles is the lcm of their lengths, the only way to get order $15$ is with 15-cycles, or with a product of 5-cycles and 3-cycles.Just remember the lcm of $a$ and $b$ is their product divided by their gcd.

Answer (score 1):

In $S_7$ there can't be elements of the cycle types which would lead to $15$ as order (namely $(a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5)(a_6a_7a_8)$ and $(a_1\dots a_{15})$), because $S_7$ comprises all and only the permutations on $7$ symbols. So, there are elements of order $15$ in $S_n$ only for $n\ge 8$.